# Canonical equation of tangent line to space curve using determinants

Tags: determinant, tangent-line

Suppose a space curve $\gamma$ is given via

$$\gamma:\begin{cases}\Phi_1(x,y,z)=0,\\\Phi_2(x,y,z)=0\end{cases}$$
where $x,y,z$ are, in turn, functions of $t$:

\begin{cases}x=\phi(t),\\y=\psi(t),\\z=\chi(t).\end{cases}

The task is to find tangent line equation to the curve $\gamma.$ So far, I have shown that

$$\frac{\frac{\mathrm{dx}}{\mathrm{dt}}}{\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial z}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial y}}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{dy}}{\mathrm{dt}}}{\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial z}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial z}}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{dz}}{\mathrm{dt}}}{\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial z}}.\ \ \ \ (1)$$

The form given in the textbook is

$$\frac{X-x}{\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial z}\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{Y-y}{\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial x}\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{Z-z}{\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial y}\end{vmatrix}},\ \ \ (2)$$

or, equivalently,

$$\frac{X-x}{\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial z}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial y}}=\frac{Y-y}{\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial z}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial z}}=\frac{Z-z}{\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial z}}.\ \ \ (2')$$
Here $(X,Y,Z)$ are the coordinates of any point on the tangent line.

> **Question**: What is the transition from $(1)$ to $(2')$?

Comment: A question of vocabulary: the term "line" used on the first line (no intended pun) and later in your text, is, by far, not as usual as the term "space curve".Besides, these space curves are obtained by intersection of 2 surfaces, a point that should be stressed.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Apologies. A silly semi-direct translation mistake on my part. Will edit. (P.S. Reasonable pun.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to your question is a rewriting of your proportionalities under the following vectorial terms:

$$\tag{1}\vec{S}=\pmatrix{\frac{\mathrm{dx}}{\mathrm{dt}}\\ \frac{\mathrm{dy}}{\mathrm{dt}} \\ \frac{\mathrm{dz}}{\mathrm{dt}}} \ \ \text{prop}^{al} \  to \ \ \vec{N_1} \times \vec{N_2}=\pmatrix{\frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial x}\\ \frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial z}} \times \pmatrix{\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial x}\\ \frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial z}} \ \ \text{prop}^{al} \  to \ \vec{M_0M}=\pmatrix{X-x_0\\Y-y_0\\Z-z_0}$$

(where $\vec{N_k}$ is a normal vector in point $M_0 (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to the surface with equation $\Phi_k(x,y,z)=0$ for $k=1,2$).

In fact, (1) describes plainly 3 ways to express a directing vector of the tangent line at $M_0.$